# Converting deprecated PHP SQL commands to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Recently looking through some old files and realised that they are now deprecated. I've tried converting them into the newer PDO variant, but I'm stuck on something. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$team=$_POST['team'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$dbHandle=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;","user","password",array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false));
$query=$dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(?,?,?)");
if(!is_numeric($user)){
    echo "Error message 1";
}elseif($user=="123"){
    echo "Error message 2";
}else{
    $query->execute(array($user,$team,"pending"));
    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
        echo "Success message";
    }else{
        echo "Error message 3";
    }
}
?>
```

Nothing I've tried seems to get the success message. It looks like most of the code is working, because it always ends up giving me the third error message every time, and I can confirm that nothing has been added to the database. Not shown above are the three lines of code for enabling all PHP error messages, but the page isn't throwing up any such messages.

Also, while I'm at it, I'm still not entirely familiar with PDO, but from the way I understood it, it's much more secure. From what I have above, are there any security risks, and if so, how should I fix them?

EDIT: The code is currently as thus:

```
<?php
    $team=$_POST['team'];
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $dbHandle=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;","user","password",array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false));
    $query=$dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(?,?,?)");
    if(!is_numeric($user)){
        echo "Error message 1";
    }elseif($user=="123"){
        echo "Error message 2";
    }else{
        $query->execute(array($user,$team,"pending"));
        if($query->rowCount()>0){
            echo "Success message";
        }else{
            echo "Error message 3";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the content of $team, $user? Is it correct with the SQL types?

Comment: A tip: `mysql_affected_rows()` is the issue here.

Comment: @AndrzejOśmiałowski: What's wrong with it? Incompatible with PDO? Shouldn't make a difference, unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: As `PDO::prepare()` returns a PDOStatement object this function will just won't work. You should use `PDOStatement::rowCount` (manual link: http://pl1.php.net/pdostatement.rowcount). But first, you really need to read PDO documentation as it may be hard to understand how does it work for newcomers.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Happy to see migration happening!

Comment: I'm just OCD about outdated things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,"user","password", $opt);
$stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stm->execute(array($_POST['user'],$_POST['team'],"pending"));
echo "Success message";
```

Comment: I'll have to keep those error options in mind. If I had them enabled originally, I would have found out that the number I was typing into the user ID field was a duplicate, and the reason why it wouldn't work. By the way, what does the FETCH_MODE line do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mysql_affected_rows()` function **is not PDO**, you should use `->rowCount()` method to know the value of affected rows. Also, I would preffer to add parameters in a separated instruction specifying the correct type with constants like `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR`, so you can avoid errors:

```
$query=$dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(?,?,?)");
if(!is_numeric($user)){
    echo "Error message 1";
}elseif($user=="123"){
    echo "Error message 2";
}else{ 
    $status = "pending";
    $query->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(2, $team, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(3, $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        echo "Success message";
    }else{
        echo "Error message 3";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah, I should be thanking you! So what does the number represent? Is it just an identifier to allow differentiation between the different bindParams?

Comment: The number indicates the order of the parameter in the SQL sentence. Because there are three ? symbols, so you can tell it which one it is

Comment: this number just makes code bloated with no reason nor any benefit. you had your code all right but now you have it worse

Comment: Testing it live, I get the following PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in..." The line it refers to is the third bindParam

Comment: Not convinced that will work, "pending" is not a parameter and will likely throw an error.

Comment: Aye, it did. Should I make a line $pending="pending";?

Comment: Fixed, added $status variable, look again the answer

Comment: @Hiigaran JUST KEEP YOUR OLD CODE `$query->execute(array($user,$team,"pending"));` which is all right instead this erroneous and bloated one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Doing so gives me the Error message 3 again. Same as the method with the $status variable. Database isn't showing a new entry, either.

Comment: @Hiigaran YOUR PROBLEM IS NOT EXECUTE BUT mysql_affected_rows